# Black background on iOS5/6 (Safari, Ipad, Iphone)

Tags: iphone, css

I have contact form with input[type="text"] and select fields.
For those elements i setup background image without any transparent pixels

But on iOS devices it's black

CSS code:

```
border:1px solid #909090; 
height:19px; 
width:344px; 
background:#fff url(../img/input-bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x
```

Nothing else overwrite those styles.
What's the problem?

Comment: post more of the relevant HTML and CSS. Not enough here to go on

Answer (score 1):

You may either:

1. Re-save the files as other image files (JPEG, GIF)
2. If it is a gradient image, then you may use [CSS3 Gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to achieve the effect.